# How to cycle through different styles for a button onClick in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, onclick

I am new to React and I was hoping someone could help me with this issue. I have a number of buttons that I want to be able to click and change the background color of in a cycle. I initially set it up to work for 2 colors but I realized I want a neutral color for never being clicked.

Right now, the code is set up so it only changes in-between 2 colors (and must start using one of the two as the default) using a ternary statement and I'm unsure how to refactor the code to include a third.

I want it to go gray, red, blue then back to gray on the 3rd click to start the cycle over.

This is the current code

```
  export default function letter({ letter }) {
  let upper = letter.toUpperCase();

  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setFlag(!flag);
  };

  return (
    <button
      className="letterBtns"
      onClick={handleClick}
      variant="contained"
      style={{ backgroundColor: flag ? "salmon" : "lightblue" }}
    >
      {upper}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function letter({ letter }) {
let upper = letter.toUpperCase();
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
let bgColorList = ['gray', 'red', 'blue']

const [flag, setFlag] = useState(null);

const handleClick = () => {
 let ctrTemp = counter >= 2 ? 0 : counter +1
 setCounter(ctrTemp)
 setFlag(!flag);
};

return (
 <button
  className="letterBtns"
  onClick={handleClick}
  variant="contained"
  style={{ backgroundColor: bgColorList[counter] }}
 >
  {upper}
 </button>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update like this with `array` and `index` to get vaue

```
const colors = ["gray", "red", "blue"];
const [flag, setFlag] = useState(0);

const handleClick = () => {
  setFlag(flag === 2 ? 0 : flag + 1);
};

style={{ backgroundColor: colors[flag] }}
```